# How to watch a column of a 2-D matrix in Visual Studio 2017 debug mode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

guys.

I know we can watch an array in the VS debug mode by adding the array into the watch window, but how do we view a column of a matrix (2D array)? Let's say we have a matrix A[3][3], and I only want to see all elements in the third column in the debug mode. I tried to type A[][2] or A[:][2] or A[,][2] in the watch window, but neither of these 3 are recognizable.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Wang, any update? If i misunderstanding anything, please feel free to contact me.  If the reply is helpful for you, please mark it as answer, it will be beneficial to other community members which has the similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

> We can't get column values in debug mode for now, at least
>   not directly.

The [watch window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019) is designed to watch variables and expressions during debug mode. **It can't recognize the variable which is not recognized by compiler.**

e.g: Let's say we have a matrix A[3][3],compiler can recognize `A` variable, `A[2]` variable, but not for something like `A[][2]`(It's an invalid variable). Correspondingly, it won't be recognized by watch window.

If you have a scenario in which you have a large 2-D matrix, and you do need the column value for some reason. You could create a single-dimensional array,iterate your 2-D array and put the 3rd column value into it. Then add the single-dimensional array variable into watch window.

We do have many workarounds to get the column value in debug mode, but to watch the column of array in debug mode directly, I'm afraid the answer is negative.**This option is not supported in vs2017 now.**

In addition:Not sure what language you use, but if you use .net(C#,VB), the A[3][3] is [A jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays), not a [two-dimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real matrix, but just **array of arrays**, so I think there is no build in method to get this.

But with `linq` you can try something like this:

```cs
A.select(a => a[2]).toArray()
```

To use `linq` in the watch window, you'll need to add the following line to the top of the code:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```